# Option in Visual Studio 2012 that allows to see extended output during compilation

Tags: visual-studio

Please remind me where is that option. I want to see all events happening during compilation and execution, for example all libraries and their functions that are found in included external libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run, change "MSBuild project build output verbosity".

This is just for the build/compilation.